# How to reset all themes

Tags: themes, settings, reset

My themes have gotten pretty messed up (installed different icon sets and controls etc, made custom themes combining different elements)
Is there an easy way to just remove all the custom themes and return to the original set of themes (and icons, controls etc) ? It would really help!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try removing the .themes folder in your home folder, so:
`rm -r .themes`
to delete it.  I would rename it first to see if it does what you want, and then delete it.  So: `mv .themes themes` and if that works, then delete the 'themes' folder in your home.

Comment: That is just for the themes installed by the user, I believe. If the included themes themselves were altered, this might not work.

Comment: Correct, however customizing themes via gnome-appearance-properties can't change anything in /usr/themes anyway, so this is a per-user issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could try reinstalling the `light-themes` package via Synaptic to reset the default Ambiance and Radiance themes.

(There may be some other packages for the other included themes, like `gnome-themes-ubuntu` and maybe others; please add them here if you know the rest.)